# Getting the last values of a collection in NodeJS/Mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm trying to get the last values(latest updates) on this array, but the code below just returns the last object/objects of all. If I increase the limit to 5, I get 2 apples 2 bananas 1 cherry. I just need the last values for all. I have 20 fruits for this and 150+ entries. I need to pick latest values for 20 fruits.
Thank you for your help.

```
const last_finder = function (collectionName) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db(dbName);
        dbo.collection(collectionName).find({}, {sort:{_id:-1}}).limit(1).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            db.close();
        });
    });
}
```

```
The result:
{
    _id: 0,
    date: ' 01:30:51',
    name: 'Banana',
    value: '3.9'
  },
  {
    _id: 1,
    date: ' 01:33:51',
    name: 'Apple',
    value: '2.45'
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    date: ' 01:34:50',
    name: 'Banana',
    value: '3.8'
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    date: ' 01:34:59',
    name: 'Cherry',
    value: '6.21'
  },
  {
    _id: 4,
    date: ' 01:40:50',
    name: 'Apple',
    value: '2.55'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose is little weird when it comes to limiting and offset, you need an exec function after limit,

```
dbo.collection(collectionName).find({}, {sort:{_id:-1}}).limit(1).exec(function(e, data){
        console.log(data)
});
```